How $D-f=e^{D^{-1}f}De^{-D^{-1}f}$ and $T-f=(T\prod f)\Delta(\prod f)^{-1}$ are connected
I have just learnt how to convert an operator containing addition into chained operators so that its inversion can be computed explicitly, here is what I meant:
Differential: $$D-f=e^{D^{-1}f}De^{-D^{-1}f}, (f =f(t))\tag{1}$$
Difference: $$T-f=(T\prod f)\Delta(\prod f)^{-1}, (f=f(n))\tag{2}$$
Explaining my symbols:
$D=\frac{d}{dt}; D^{-1}=\int ()dt; T(x_{n})=x_{n+1}; \Delta(x_n)=x_{n+1}-x_{n}; \Delta^{-1}(x_{n})=C+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i}); \prod f(n)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}f(i)$
The only relation between differential operators and difference operators I know is:
$$e^{D}=T=\Delta+1 \tag{3}$$
I could convince myself that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true by deriving them from scratch but seperately. The reason this got me interested because after seeing Euler method, I believe there is a deep structure similarity between the "continuous" calculus and the "discrete" calculus.
One more thing I observed, operator with parameter $h$: $O_{h} f(x):=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}O_{h}=D$ and $O_{1}=\Delta$ so if there is a formula generalizing both $(1)$ and $(2)$ with parameter $h$, we can see how they are connected. But how do I find such thing? Moreover, given $(3)$, is it possible to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent?
